# Dando ctrl + f em webbrowser pelo código

Tags: c#, winforms

Sabem de alguma forma de dar <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> em alguma coisa pelo código em uma instância de WebBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

A classe [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) pode ser utilizada para enviar combinações de teclas para a aplicação em primeiro plano.

Para enviar <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> use:

```
SendKeys.Send("^f");
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar depois e ver no que da :)